# Whatever I try to install I get errors

Tags: system-installation

I Cant install or upgrade anything without encountering errors.

[image]

Comment: What things can't you update?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is still a supported release; so whomever changed it to old-releases.ubuntu.com made an error.  Ubuntu isn't Debian and doesn't upgrade that way if you wish to avoid problems.  If you want specific help, please don't provide a picture of text - we can't copy & paste specific details with what needs changing from a picture.